# How to calculate modulus without the operator and any round function?

Tags: rounding, pseudocode, modulus

I have to calculate the modulus of a number to check if it's even or not, but **the only instruction to compare two numbers is checking if they're equal**, and there **isn't the modulus operator and a function\operator to round numbers**.

A way to round numbers would be an alternative to modulus operator, but i can't find a solution to either modulus and round.

Just need a **pseudo code** to work with.

We're learning some assembly basics at school with a "pseudo" assembly (DuplOne).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the number to test is not negative, and that subtract and jump instructions are available, check if the number is 1 (i.e. the original number was odd) or 0 (i.e. the original number was even), otherwise subtract 2 and go back to the checks.

```
:label
    if number = 1 then
        original number is odd
        finish
    if number = 0 then
        original number is even
        finish
    subtract 2 from number
    go to label
```